# How to read string from streams

Tags: string, stream

```
        Dim adult = webClient.DownloadString("http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?callback=_google_json_callback&output=js&client=ca-dp-godaddy2_xml&domain_name=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
        'ias.NavigateTillComplete("https://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
        Dim result = ""
        Dim url = "http://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain
        Dim webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        Dim response = DirectCast(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream
        Dim responseString = responseStream.readAll? 'MethodAccessException doesn't exist


        Dim responseString = responseStream.readAll? 'MethodAccessException doesn't exist
```

How should I replace             `Dim responseString = responseStream.readAll`?

What's the actual command?

Comment: What is so unreal about this question? Somebody gives good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the response stream to a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) instance and then use the [`ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method:

```
Dim adult = webClient.DownloadString("http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?callback=_google_json_callback&output=js&client=ca-dp-godaddy2_xml&domain_name=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
'ias.NavigateTillComplete("https://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
Dim result = ""
Dim url = "http://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain
Dim webRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
Using Dim response = DirectCast(webRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Using Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream
        Using Dim responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream)
            Dim responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

But why bother with an HttpWebRequest when you could use a WebClient directly:

```
Dim adult = webClient.DownloadString("http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/apps/domainpark/domainpark.cgi?callback=_google_json_callback&output=js&client=ca-dp-godaddy2_xml&domain_name=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
'ias.NavigateTillComplete("https://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain)
Dim result = ""
Dim url = "http://api.bodis.com/domainclassification?domain=" + CurrentBlog.Domain
Dim responseString = webClient.DownloadString(url)
```

Comment: webclient  has problems.

Comment: What problems? I have never had any problems with it.

Comment: When the downloadstring fail there is no way to get the response at all.

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot get the response at all and when downloadstring fail? Catching a WebException from this method call you could always read the response from the server. I really do not understand what problems you are encountering.